# Aptana Studio 3 - Can't check typo errors?

Tags: aptana, spelling

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 for learning JavaScript. I'm start to like this IDE but one of its disadvantages is that when I made a type error such as:

```
if (comfirm("are you sure ?")) // "coMfirm", the right one is "confirm"
{
    alert("you answered yes");
}
else
{
    alert("you answered NO");
}
```

Then when I hit the Run button, the IDE just ignored this error and continue to run my current file. I think this kind of errors is so hard to be recognized by naked eye & it makes my learning progress meets many difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not a matter of Aptana Studio but a matter of Javascript.
Use Firefox to run your code. Then in firefox right click your page and from the menu select the last item (with (Q)). In firefox below opens a new footer select "Console" and "JS". It will show you the error 'ReferenceError: comfirm is not defined' and on the right edge it shows the filename and line number.